# Month Name in regional language and wanted in English

Tags: excel

I use this formula to get the first three letters of the month with first letter in capital (i.e. Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, ...) :

```
=UPPER(LEFT(TEXT(B1;"mmm");1)) & MID(TEXT(B1;"mmm");2;2)
```

But it give the result to me in my **own language and I want it in English**.

My **Excel and all Office are in English**, I just have French **regional settings** (that I prefer to keep, or I don't really want to switch them every time I use that kind of function).

> Is there any way to change the language of the output of `TEXT` function?

Comment: @pnuts : Indeed, it is not a really complex formula development. But though the tag shouldn't have anything to do with VBA, as there is already a dedicated tag to VBA and one for VBA in each Office App... It might be time to get rid of this...

Comment: @pnuts : I was talking about the wiki, but mostly the part about VBA, even if the *Only for questions on complex formula development* seems indeed useless regarding most of the questions that must be posted under that tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @Amit great response, I would say: `=TEXT(B1;"[$-409]mmm")`.

As the English name of Month are already capitalized on the first letter.

If it's not enough, there is the `Proper` function that will only capitalize the first letter of the word.

---

format mmm already is 3 char long in English. No need for LEFT(). Proper() capitalizes the first char only.
Note that using 040C for French for example, it might return longer strings ! E.g: "Juil." for July.

Comment: Thx for contribution, I already accepted @Amit answer's. But your's reminded me that nice function that is `Proper`, I'm gonna simplify my formulas right now!

Comment: As per my comment above, you shouldn't need either LEFT function or PROPER - the returned string should already have 3 characters and be capitalised (i.e. the first character like "Jul")......is that not the case for you? What do you get with `=TEXT(B1;"[$-409]mmm")`?

Comment: @barryhoudini : Indeed it is, so I really simplify my formula, thanks for all your help! Just edited answer to reflect what has been said around!

Answer (score 6):

You can force `TEXT` to use a specific locale (English US in your case...).
Try this: `=UPPER(LEFT(TEXT(B1;"[$-409]mmm");1)) & MID(TEXT(B1;"[$-409]mmm");2;2)`

Comment: This works well for me, but I'd expect the first letter to be capitalised by default by the TEXT function when getting English language months so the simple TEXT function alone should suffice, i.e. `=TEXT(B1;"[$-409]mmm")`

Comment: @barryhoudini I guess you're right, but I didn't test this at this time. Anyway, the question is about the locale, not about the string manipulation

Comment: @Amit Awesome, I saw that long time ago, but I totally forgot about it! Thx for superfast answer!

Comment: @barryhoudini : Same expectations, but as it wasn't already in capital, I had to do it myself!